# Durandal ViewModels activate repeatedly after 2.0.0 upgrade

Tags: durandal

I am upgrading my durandal project from 1.2.0 to version 2.0.0.  I have followed the steps in the durandal documentation (http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/) and the app functions as usual now.  The issue that I am seeing is that my activate callback keeps getting called over and over again.

Here is one of the viewmodels that is doing it:

```
define(['services/datacontext', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/model', 'services/images', 'services/pager'],
    function (datacontext, router, logger, model, images, pager) {

        var collaborators = ko.observableArray([]);
        var filterString = ko.observable();
        var pageHandler = new pager();

        var activate = function (filter) {
            return Q.all([datacontext.getAll(model.entityNames.songwriter + 's', "", collaborators, { orderBy: "firstName" })])
                    .then(dataRetrieved)
                    .then(activatePager);

            function dataRetrieved() {
            };

            function activatePager() {
                pageHandler.init.call(pageHandler, collaborators(), {
                    pageSize: 12,
                    filterCallback: function (item) {
                        var filter = filterString().toLowerCase();

                        var pred1 = item.fullName().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0;

                        return pred1;
                    }
                });
                if (filter != null) {
                    filterString(filter);
                    pageHandler.applyFilter.call(pageHandler);
                }
            };
        };

        var deactivate = function () {
        };

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            deactivate: deactivate,
            collaborators: pageHandler.displayItems,
            title: 'Collaborators',
            images: images,
            router: router,
            pager: pageHandler,
            filterString: filterString
        };

        return vm;
    });
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Here is the chrome console output:

[image: Chrome Console]

**Edit**

This doesn't seem to be happening on all viewmodels, this one is fine..

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/datacontext', 'plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/model', 'viewmodels/shared/leftnav', 'viewmodels/modals/imagecrop', 'services/images'],
    function (app, datacontext, router, logger, model, leftnav, imagecrop, images) {
        leftnav.area("Songwriter");

        var songwriter = ko.observable();
        var songwriterId = ko.observable();
        var publishers = ko.observableArray([]);
        var pros = ko.observableArray([]);

        var activate = function (id) {
            songwriterId(id);
            leftnav.entityId(songwriterId());

            return Q.all([datacontext.getEntityById(model.entityNames.songwriter, songwriterId(), "Publisher, Pro", songwriter),
                          datacontext.getAll(model.entityNames.publisher + 's', "", publishers),
                          datacontext.getAll(model.entityNames.pro + 's', "", pros)]);
        };

        var deactivate = function () {
            if (datacontext.hasChanges()) {
                datacontext.cancelChanges();
            }
        };

        var saveClick = function () {
            datacontext.saveChanges().then(saveComplete);

            function saveComplete() {
                router.navigateBack();
            };
        };

        var cancelClick = function () {
            router.navigateBack();
        };

        var imageUploaded = function (e) {
            logger.logSuccess("Image Uploaded Successfully", e.response, "Profile", true);
            songwriter().photoFilePath('/azure/profileimages/' + e.response);

            app.showDialog(imagecrop, {
                title: 'Crop Profile Image',
                message: '<i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Your profile image needs to be cropped to ensure that it does not appear distorted.',
                filePath: songwriter().photoFilePath()
            }).then(appendCropInfo);

            function appendCropInfo(coords) {
                var path = songwriter().photoFilePath;

                path(path() + '?crop=(' + coords.x + ',' + coords.y + ',' + coords.x2 + ',' + coords.y2 + ')');
            };
        };


        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            deactivate: deactivate,
            songwriter: songwriter,
            publishers: publishers,
            pros: pros,
            title: 'Songwriter',
            cancelClick: cancelClick,
            saveClick: saveClick,
            imageUploaded: imageUploaded,
            images: images
        };

        return vm;
    });
```

**Edit - Stack Trace**

```
activate (details.js:11)
invoke (activator.js:52)
activate (activator.js:99)
(anonymous function) (activator.js:308)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3070)
fire (jquery-2.0.3.js:2914)
self.add (jquery-2.0.3.js:2960)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3069)
jQuery.extend.each (jquery-2.0.3.js:590)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3065)
jQuery.extend.Deferred (jquery-2.0.3.js:3126)
promise.then (jquery-2.0.3.js:3064)
(anonymous function) (activator.js:306)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3070)
fire (jquery-2.0.3.js:2914)
self.add (jquery-2.0.3.js:2960)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3069)
jQuery.extend.each (jquery-2.0.3.js:590)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3065)
jQuery.extend.Deferred (jquery-2.0.3.js:3126)
promise.then (jquery-2.0.3.js:3064)
(anonymous function) (activator.js:302)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3070)
fire (jquery-2.0.3.js:2914)
self.add (jquery-2.0.3.js:2960)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3069)
jQuery.extend.each (jquery-2.0.3.js:590)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3065)
jQuery.extend.Deferred (jquery-2.0.3.js:3126)
promise.then (jquery-2.0.3.js:3064)
(anonymous function) (activator.js:300)
jQuery.extend.Deferred (jquery-2.0.3.js:3126)
system.defer (system.js:218)
computed.activateItem (activator.js:285)
activateRoute (router.js:248)
handleGuardedRoute (router.js:303)
ensureActivation (router.js:313)
(anonymous function) (router.js:357)
(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3070)
fire (jquery-2.0.3.js:2914)
self.fireWith (jquery-2.0.3.js:3026)
deferred.(anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.3.js:3115)
(anonymous function) (system.js:256)
```

**Edit - Route**

The route is configured as follows:

```
{ route: 'songwriter/:id', moduleId: 'songwriter/details', nav: true, title: 'Profile', settings: { icon: 'icon-edit' } },
```

Comment: How is the first view model being composed? Is it a partial view, modal dialog, etc.?

Comment: The first view model is a full view.  It is composed the same as the second one.

Comment: Hard to tell. There's a lot of code missing that I can only guess at what it's doing. Add `debugger;` as the first line in your `activate()` function and step through the code to figure out what keeps triggering it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is a part of a massive project.  I've added the debugger statement, however, I can't determine what is causing it to cycle.

Comment: Are you using a child router?

Comment: @mcottingham Look at the call stack in the browser's developer tools when it halts on the `debugger;` statement. You can then double-click on one of the preceding entries and work your way up the call chain to get some idea of what's happening.

Comment: @margabit I am not using a child router.

Comment: @brett I have uploaded the stack trace, is anything standing out to you?

Comment: @mcottingham can you show how the router is configured?

Comment: @margabit the route config has been added above.

Answer (score 0):

Can be the same problem I am observing after upgrade to 2.0.
I have posted a similar case at Durandal Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/durandaljs/rOQ8EfFb1tM

I created a repo to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/stiankroknes/durandal-router-problem

Comment: Yes, this looks to be the same issue.  Has any progress been made towards a solution?

Comment: Yes, it is a bug in Durandal 2. See recent comments: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/rOQ8EfFb1tM